# C# Get standard input/output/error of running, NOT child process

Tags: c#, winapi, process

My question is pretty simple: how do I get the standard output/input/error of a process I did not start? Let's say I have some program (that is not mine) XYZ that runs all day and prints things to stdout. I want to be able to start my C# application and start reading XYZ's output. Then close my C# application and restart it 2 hours later and continue reading the output (not necessarily where I left off but that would be a plus).

I know this can be achieved if XYZ is a child process of mine with

```
serverProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    WorkingDirectory = WorkingDir,
    Arguments = Args,
    FileName = "XYZ",
    UseShellExecute = false
});
serverProcess.OutputDataReceived += serverProcess_OutputDataReceived;
serverProcess.ErrorDataReceived += serverProcess_OutputDataReceived;
serverProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
serverProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

But this is not the case since XYZ is is completely independent of my application, and needs to keep running regardless of what I do to it.
It is worth noting that (if it helps) I can start XYZ myself (with those redirection parameters). It's just that my lifecycle needs to be completely independent of XYZ, and I need to be able to "reattach" after I relaunch.

I have seen some suggestions using Get/SetStdHandle but most of them claimed to not work, and I din't quite understand how to apply them anyways.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Isn't there a security principle against this? You could divert stdin/stdout of any process this way and mimick whatever input you want. I don't think that allowing this without help from the process would be a good idea for any secure OS.

On Linux the process has to open named pipes or UNIX sockets to be connected to and that is **on purpose** required.

I wouldn't be surprised if Windows requires the same collaboration, but if someone can prove me wrong I'll be pleased to learn how to do this :)

Comment: Well then can I not have some kind of wrapper/blackbox process running that starts XYZ using the redirection technique above and then in turn redirects everything to the Windows equivalent of the sockets you mentioned? i.e. this wrapper can provide whatever collaboration I need?

Comment: @Roman my suggestion is that you create an intermediary process which starts the XYZ and do the redirection, then simply start publishing the redirected results ( it can simply done using libraries like ZeroMQ).

Comment: The wrapper would transform your problem into a simple redirection of a child process. You already show the code in your question so you've the answer there. Next, make it accessible with the ZeroMQ techinique proposed by user3473830 (which is an excellent idea) or dump the output to a file, which is expensive and requires proper *file rolling*, otherwise you'll end up with a full disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is worth noting that (if it helps) I can start XYZ myself (with those redirection parameters). It's just that my lifecycle needs to be completely independent of XYZ, and I need to be able to "reattach" after I relaunch.

Here is a simple implementation of what I suggested in the comments (publishing data through an intermediary process).

basicaly the sample is composed of 3 main parts

**1. Sample XYZ Process**

which in our case, is a simple console application that spits a Hello from XYZ message every second.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var count = 0;
           while (true)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Hello from XYZ "+count);
               count++;
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
           }
       }
    }
```

**2. Intermediary Process**

which should start XYZ and redirect its output to itself and then publish it through. for publishing part we use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org) library here that can be obtained easily from nuget.

```
class Program
{
    private static Socket _pub;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            _pub = context.Socket(SocketType.PUB);
            _pub.Bind("tcp://*:2550");

            StartXyz();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close middle process...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static void StartXyz()
    {
         var serverProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            Arguments = string.Empty,
            FileName = "XYZ.exe",
            UseShellExecute = false
        });
        serverProcess.OutputDataReceived += serverProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        serverProcess.ErrorDataReceived += serverProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        serverProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        serverProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }

    private static void serverProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        _pub.Send(e.Data, Encoding.UTF8);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data + " pushed.");
    }
}
```

**3. Consumer Process**

and finally we have our process, which consumes redirected data from XYZ.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var sub = context.Socket(SocketType.SUB);
            sub.Connect("tcp://localhost:2550");
            sub.Subscribe(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8);
            while (true)
            {
                var data = sub.Recv(Encoding.UTF8);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach seems to fit well. Thanks!